# Cron does not update currency rates

Tags: magento-1, cron, currency

I'm using this module to replace webservicex currency rates importer:
https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_Fixerio

It is working ok when I hit import and save in the backend.

But I want to run it via a cron.

So I added to the module's config:

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <fixerio>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>fixerio/import::_convert</model>
            </run>
        </fixerio>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

And then run it with magerun:

```
./n98-magerun.phar sys:cron:run fixerio
```

It appears ok in the database and don't get errors in the console.

But the rates aren't modified in System -> Manage currencies.

If I insert a random value and save it then after the cron it will not update.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should manage the currency import in `System -> configuration -> manage currencies`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change your cron schedule to `<cron_expr>0 * * * *</cron_expr>` once an hour instead of checking every minute.

Maybe the cron process isn't pulling through the fixer.io key?  This could be a store scope issue.  Cron process with use admin store values unless coded otherwise.

Although you shouldn't need this XML.  This extension uses the built in magento cron process

> Import the rates nightly by setting up the job to do so. Navigate to System > Config > Currency Settings > Scheduled Import Settings and select Fixer.io from the dropdown. Also enable the service if not previously enabled.

[image: Schedule]